# Ruby: The most elegant way to detect turning points in Array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Let's take the following Array:

```
[1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 4]
```

It has the following turning points (when rise changes to fall, or vice versa):

- 5 (at index 2)
- 1 (at index 4)
- 6 (at index 6)

To make task more general:

- There is an Array `a = [a1, a2, ...]`
- There is function `p(x,y) -> z`, where `z` is `Comparable`
- How to get all elements a<sub>i</sub> ∈ a (0 < i < a.length-1) for which p(a<sub>i-1</sub>, a<sub>i</sub>) != p(a<sub>i</sub>, a<sub>i+1</sub>)

I would like to write something like:

```
a.detect_edges{|prev, n| prev >= n} # => [[5,2], [1, 4], [6,6]]
```

What's the most elegant way to get those turning points with their respective indexes? Here's my code with which I'm not satisfied from the aesthetic point of view:

```
class Array
  def detect_edges(&blk)
    return nil if self.length < 2
    prev = blk.call(self[0], self[1])
    result = []
    self[0..-2].each_with_index do |elem, i|
      current = blk.call(elem, self[i+1])
      if current != prev
        result.push [elem, i]
      end
      prev = current
    end
    result
  end
end
```

Comment: Why isn't the `1` between `3` and `4` a turning point in your example?

Comment: @ndn, for the purpose of simplicity – I've written that I counted turning points "from rise to fall". Sorry if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: @ndn But at the end, that didn't make that more simple :) Thanks for pointing that out, I will redact my question.

Comment: Try https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 4]
.each_cons(3).with_index(1)
.reject{|(e1, e2, e3), i| (e1 <=> e2) == (e2 <=> e3)}
.map{|(e1, e2, e3), i| [e2, i]}
# => [[5, 2], [1, 4], [6, 6]]
```

Comment: This should be answer of the month or so.

Comment: Nice use of destructuring!

Answer (score 4):

Look ma, no `map`!

```
a = [1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 4]

a[1..-2].each.with_index(1).reject { |e,i| (a[i-1]<=>e) == e<=>a[i+1] }    
  #=> [[5, 2], [1, 4], [6, 6]]
```

Comment: Why don't you do `a[1...-1].each.with_index(1).reject ...`?

Comment: @sawa, I tried to do that, but something so simple didn't occur to me. Good to know. I'll use it in future. Makes you wonder why `each_with_index` doesn't take a parameter. Thanks, edited. Oops, I see I forgot something. (Probably the subject of an unread comment. It was.)

Comment: @sawa, a detail: I prefer `a[1..-2]` to `a[1...-1]` because I think there's a chance the latter will be mis-read as having two dots or I will mistakingly put two dots.. In general, I try to consistently use two dots, but will opt for three to avoid, for example, `..x-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want the elements and their indices, where the element is the local max in a 1 index range:

```
arr.each.with_index.select { |element, index| element == arr[index.pred..index.next].max }
  # => [[5, 2], [6, 6]]
```

Note, you have to handle the case for the first element or if elements are equal.

---

**EDIT**: for your updated version, you just have to check if the result of `<=>` has changed. Note that you will again have to check the case when elements are equal:

```
arr.each.with_index.to_a.tap(&:pop).drop(1).select do |element, index| 
  (arr[index.pred] <=> element) != (element <=> arr[index.next])
end # => [[5, 2], [1, 4], [6, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see reason to get more fancy than:

```
class Array
  def detect_edges
    self.collect.with_index do |e, i|
      next if i == 0 || i >= size-1
      yield(self[i-1],e) != yield(e,self[i+1]) ? [e, i] : nil
    end.compact
  end
end
```

Note that when patching `Array` one should probably use refinements.

Comment: I choose your answer, and it's a bit subjective. But actually you are the only one who provided actual `Array` method implementation, instead of ad-hoc method calls. And furthermore, I like the implementation itself more than others', and that's the subjective part. Also, fixed mistake with index bounds.

Comment: I just added a notice in order not to promote quite a bad practice in accepted answer.